# How to play m3u8 format in iPhone

Tags: ios4

I have got a url http://stream.alayam.com/alayam/alayam/playlist.m3u8 and wanted to play in iPhone, with m3u8 format, I have successfully got the voice, however movie is not coming. I have used MPMEDIAPLAYER framework and other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving u answer in new answer because code will be more readable.
I just download MPMovieController example from Apple website and then add your link with `http://`

In `NSURL` i pass link `http://stream.alayam.com/alayam/alayam/playlist.m3u8` not this one `stream.alayam.com/alayam/alayam/playlist.m3u8` and it works fine.

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL
    {
    // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if (mp)
    {
        // save the movie player object
        self.moviePlayer = mp;
        [mp release];

        // Apply the user specified settings to the movie player object
        [self setMoviePlayerUserSettings];

        // Play the movie!
        [self.moviePlayer play];
    }
}
```

Comment: the link from where i download example is http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Listings/Classes_MyViewController_m.html

Comment: thanks for all the information, i am going to check it right now